# Spinning Roulette in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I recently started learning to code. I'm trying to make an app with a spinning roulette and found this online. I can get the roulette to spin, but it ends up in the same exact place every time I spin it, so I want it to end up in a random place every new spin. I hope somebody could help. Thanks in advance!

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: [UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut], animations: {

        for _ in 0..<10 {
            self.ruleRut.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 1))
            self.ruleRut.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Read about `arc4random_uniform` to generate a randomised angle.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here. The first is that this is a question involving several points of which Swift is the least important. Let's break down what is happening in your sample:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: 
[UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut], animations:
```

Here you are using a UIKit (not specific to Swift) animation helper that will run to whichever end state over the course of 5 seconds. In the closure, you define what the end states are, and it will use an `ease-out` curve (decelerating) to get there in animated form.

```
{
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        self.ruleRut.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 1))
        self.ruleRut.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
    }
})
```

Here, it gets a little confusing. You are telling UIKit that you want `ruleRut` to rotate `pi` radians (180 degrees) and then rotate to 0 degrees from 0 to 9 times because of this for loop, so the meaning gets a bit lost. This might work, but expect it to be a hack.

As to your question of why it always stops at the same spot, you are calling rotation transforms in increments of 180 degrees, and in an even number of rotations, you will always end up where you started. You'll want to randomize the radians you rotate by to achieve the desired end point. You'll also have to deal with which direction the view is rotating, which is out of scope for this answer, but basically involves using more complex explicit animations, or making sure that the animation happens over fewer than 180 degrees. In any case, your best bet is probably to start with Apple's documentation on the subject, linked below, and then following a tutorial by someone like Ray Wenderlich about animations in iOS.

Apple's documentation on UIView animations can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1)

Ray Wenderlich animation tutorials can be found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5255-basic-uiview-animation-tutorial-getting-started)

Hope this helps, and welcome to the world of iOS!